# Simple coding to Stack

Tags: c++11

```
int main()
{

  string sentence;
  int length;


  cout << "Enter the sentence now." << endl;
    getline(cin, sentence);


  for(int i = 0; i < sentence[i]; i++)
  {



    if(sentence[i]==';')
    cout<<" ";
    else if(sentence[i] != ' ')
    {
        cout << sentence[i];
    }
    else if(sentence[i] == ' ')
    {
        cout << endl;
    }

  }
}
```

I need help in this code to change into stack coding method. At least you can show me some clue how to change this code into simple stack code.

Comment: How do you define _stack coding method_?

Comment: @timrau: Probably code using a stack machine, but honestly this does not seem to be a particularly suitable case for that.

Comment: I understood the concept of stack but to implement it in coding is a bit hard. By using push,pop,top etc. If it is fixed in length of word, it would be not a problem. Correct me if im wrong. Ill post the answer below it is not flexible in length.

Answer (score 0):

```
cin>>a>>b>>c>>d>>e>>f>>g;
myStack.push(g);
myStack.push(f);
myStack.push(e);
myStack.push(d);
myStack.push(c);
myStack.push(b);
myStack.push(a);

while(!myStack.empty()){
    cout<<myStack.top()<<endl;
    myStack.pop();
}
return 0;
```

}

This is an example, but its not flexible. User only can enter 7 words or maybe we can do it in array?